# Yellow fever vaccination for Mauritius

Tags: south-africa, mauritius, yellow-fever

TL:DR: Do I need a yellow fever vaccination if I enter Mauritius from South Africa?

Long: I will travel to South Africa in October and afterwards, I will travel further to Mauritius. I know that [I don't need a yellow fever vaccination for South Africa, as long I don't stay in a country with risk of yellow fever before](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/yellowbook/2024/itineraries/south-africa#:%7E:text=Yellow%20Fever%20Vaccine%20Requirements&text=South%20Africa%20considers%20a%20one,quarantined%20for%20%E2%89%A46%20days.).
For Mauritius, it seems that this is the same. [I can enter the country, as long as I haven't visited a country with risk of yellow fever before](https://www.who.int/docs/default-source/documents/emergencies/travel-advice/yellow-fever-vaccination-requirements-country-list-2020-en.pdf). But all the information I found seems to be a bit older. Has someone done the same route not long ago and more actual information, if my information is true?